# SQL API, how to get started

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for some resources to get me started on how to design and implement an API for SQL.

Is this done by writing a series of functions and/or stored procedures to process your transactions on the SQL server (T-SQL).

I have read a bit about Transaction API's v Table API's. While you don't have to chose one of the other I would prefer to avoid the Table API's and focus more on Transaction API's to keep performance high and avoid using cursors.

Also from what I understand RESTFUL API's are just making the requests through HTTP requests (Using JSON) rather than connecting to the DB directly.

If my understanding is completely wrong on this subject please correct me as I am trying to learn.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use existing methods?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. What are the existing methods? 
How best do you implement this? As transactions are specific to use cases how do you handle new transactions, etc.